# What's the best way to check if a date is within a year?

Tags: r, lubridate

I feel like this should be simple, but I'm struggling to find what I want here.

I just want to check if a date is within a year. I thought something like this would work, but it doesn't:

```
filter(mdy(COV_EFF_DTE) %within% YEAR_SOLD)
```

...where COV_EFF_DTE is a date in mdy format (e.g. 1/15/2015) and YEAR_SOLD is simply an integer representing a year (e.g. 2015).

I have something that does the job, but it is really ugly and I want to simplify the code. Here's my current solution...

```
filter(mdy(COV_EFF_DTE) %within% interval(mdy(paste("1/1/",YEAR_SOLD)),mdy(paste("12/31/",YEAR_SOLD))))
```

Like I said, this works, but there must be something better. Is there a simple way to convert a year into an interval spanning 1/1/YYYY to 12/31/YYYY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `year()` in package `lubridate` to get a numeric year value from date.

```
library(lubridate)

year <- 1998L

my_date <- ymd(19980301)

year(my_date) %in% year
```

Comment: Yikes, I'm an idiot... In hindsight it seems so obvious... Thank you. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 grepl(as.character(YEAR_SOLD),COV_EFF_DTE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `year(as.Date(COV_EFF_DTE, format = '%m/%d/%Y'))` 
It will return the year and you can filter your data accordingly.